# ModelBinding throws error No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I had an API endpoint like below,

```
public ActionResult GetData([FromBody] Employee emp)
{
  
}
```

I had a class like below:

```
public class Employee : Department
{
  public string EmpName {get; set;}
  public string EmpDetails {get; set;}

}

public class Department
{
    public string DeptName {get; set;}
    public TimeZoneInfo ClientTimeZoneInfo { get; set; }
}
```

when I pass my object as below, its working fine and endpoint is hitting

```
{
  "EmpName" : "Demo",
  "EmpDetails" : "Test",
  "DeptName" : "Cargo"
}
```

But when I pass my objext like below, throwing error and endpoint is not hitting

```
{
  "EmpName" : "Demo",
  "EmpDetails" : "Test",
  "DeptName" : "Cargo",

}
```

When I click on the button on UI it will call my javaScript method replyMesaage(Employee) and obj== Employee object

```
  replyMessage(obj) {
        let that = this;
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
        // call to get the reply message partial view markup
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Messages/GetData",
            data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, model: obj },
            success: function (data) {
                $(window).scrollTop(0);
                var panelbar = $("#Dump").data("kendoPanelBar");
                panelbar.insertBefore({
                    text: "",
                    encoded: false,
                    content: data,
                    expanded: true,
                    collapse: function (e) {
                        if (e.item.class.contains('reply'))
                            e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }, panelbar.element.children("li:first"));
                var isInternal = $("#test").val();
                var message = $("#subject").val();
                var TypeValue = $("#TypeValue").val();
                that.loadRecipientList(isInternal, message, TypeValue);
            }
        });
```

Exception:
No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Could someone help me with this issue?

Full Exception:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>No parameterless constructor defined for this object.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:pointer; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>No parameterless constructor defined for this object.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.                      </code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean&amp; canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal&amp; ctor, Boolean&amp; bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark) +122
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark) +239
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +85
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +197

[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Object type &#39;System.TimeZoneInfo&#39;.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +233
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +511
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +333
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) +377
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +101
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model) +55
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +1207
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +333
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +335
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass3_1.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +640
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +346
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;BeginExecuteCore&gt;b__152_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +494
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;BeginExecute&gt;b__151_1(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +403
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__20_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +412
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +444
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +163
</pre>                      </code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4210.0

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[MissingMethodException]: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
[MissingMethodException]: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Object type &#39;System.TimeZoneInfo&#39;.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingConte…
```

Comment: Not those classes, because they *do* have a default parameterless constructor. Post the *actual full exception text*, not just the message. You can get the actual text with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup. Post the *full text*, not just parts of it. The full text contains the actual line that threw the error and the stack trace with the calls that led to this problem. Again, post the *actual full text*, not the message or stack trace separately

Comment: updated my question with a complete exception message.Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

You have two main choices :

1. Create new class EmpDept that contains  EmpName,EmpDetails and DepName properties
   and change your action to  GetData([FromBody] EmpDept empDept)
2. just change your action to  GetData([FromBody] string EmpName, string EmpDetails, string DepName=null) and in the action body create new classes with this params

Comment: I cannot go with either of the options. Is there any other option to rectify this

Comment: I am sure there are a lot of another options but I would like to see how do you call GetData action - from ajax or from the html. Please post  or ajax query or page or partial view.

Comment: updated my question, please have a look. I am doing Ajax call

Comment: The problem is data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, model: obj } . Try to use  { __RequestVerificationToken: token, emp: obj }  but I am not  sure that it will be working since I still don't understand how are you get __RequestVerificationToken value in your controller. I dont see it in ActionResult GetData([FromBody] Employee emp). Pls let me know.